# Como faço para filtrar um tempo vindo através de um select

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

```
 $query = "SELECT horario FROM tempo WHERE teste = $teste";
```

Maneira que retorna: 2019-07-26 19:24:17

Maneira que eu quero que retorne:19:24:17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) para mostrar o dado que quiser de data da forma que quiser:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(colName,'%H:%i:%s') AS horario
  FROM tempo
```

> [**`DATE_FORMAT`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)
>
> Formats the date value according to the format string.

Em tradução livre:

> Formata o valor da data de acordo com a string de formato.

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar também da seguinte forma

```
SELECT TO_DATE(horario,'HH24:MI:SS') FROM tempo WHERE teste = $teste;
```

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 10:30:15'); //10
SELECT EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 10:30:15'); //30
SELECT EXTRACT(SECOND FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 10:30:15'); //15

MySQL
SELECT TIME('2019-07-07 11:28:46'); //11:28:46